# In memory data-grid (Hazelcast) and large DB files: How to handle?

Tags: java, distributed-computing, hazelcast, in-memory-database

I have a question about processing larger data by using the Hazelcast In-Memory Data grid. I failed to find a concrete answer about the usage of this technology for the following scenario, so I turned here for help.

I have heterogeneous data sources, which are different kind of databases, for exampe Oracle, Sql Server, etc. We have a project which is going to read data from these heterogeneous sources. We are going to execute two types of operations on that data: First, we are going to take a structured sql query from a user, this query may involve very complex joins, filtering, aggregation operations and analytic functions (like the ones which Oracle supports). The result will be the creation of new tables which we are going to write into destination databases; which may be the same ones as the sources or different DBs in different machines. Second type of operations involve executing computation heavy algorithms on the data we read from the source DBs, for example executing a Gradient Descent algorithm for optimizing a statistical model we build using the data from source DBs as the training data. The result will mostly be a new table, which holds the model parameters or test data scores, for example.

For the second type of computation, I think that a distributed In-Memory data grid like Hazelcast would perform well; I may load the data into distributed Maps or Multimaps, distribute the computation load between cluster nodes and collect the results, using a MapReduce paradigm perhaps. I am mostly concerned with our first type of problem, which involves complex structured sqls. I have the following questions for which I have failed to find satisfactory answers in general; any help or pointers are very much welcome.

1) The tables in the source DBs are very large, in the scale of a few tens of GBs commonly. In this case I think that it is not a feasible, maybe even possible thing to load all of them into the Hazelcast distributed memory, RAM is still very expensive compared to disk storage and our cluster should consist of commodity machines. How should we approach this problem then; I think of a distributed central DB layer, for example like the Apache Cassandra, into which all heterogeneous sources are read. Then the structured sql queries will be run onto this central database, independent from any In-Memory computation steps.

2) How the disk persistence should be provided in a In-Memory grid setup with Hazelcast? For example, we read a large DB table into the memory (supposing it fits into the memory) into a Map structure provided by Hazelcast. Then we updated this data in the memory somehow. How should this update reflect onto the disk copy of the actual table? Does the JCache come into play here, for example by using JCache API, do we obtain coherency between disk and memory automatically or should we write manual routines which guarantee that the disk and in memory data are always consistent?

3)Finally, as far as I understood from Hazelcast documentation, Hazelcast supports Sql-like queries on the distributed Map objects with a rich set of predicates. But is it further possible that we write a completely native Sql command string and query these distributed in memory objects with them? I mean something like:

```
string sqlCommand = "SELECT A.Col1,B.Col2 FROM TABLE A LEFT JOIN TABLE B ON A.IdCol = B.IdCol WHERE A.FilterCol='X' AND B.FilterCol='Y'";
ImagineryHazelcastSqlCommandObject o = new ImagineryHazelcastSqlCommandObject (sqlCommand);
data = ImagineryHazelcastSqlCommandObject.Execute();
```

Comment: I think someone on the Hazelcast mailing list will be able to answer this. It would be great if you could link the response here.